# Pushwoosh Android notification is replaced when new come

Tags: android, push-notification, pushwoosh

I am using pushwoosh to send notification from server to devices. And that is working without any problems. Also it is worth mentioning that I am using phonegap/cordova.  This problem is only related for android, ios does not has this problem.

Problem is when I send few notifications in short time only one is displayed in android notification area. On notification handle in my code all notification are received. Notifications do not have same title or text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable multi-notifications for Android. Look for "setMultiNotificationsMode" here:
https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-android-sdk/blob/master/Documentation/PushManager.md#setmultinotificationmode

Comment: In case someone is using cordova/phonegao you should use pushNotification.setMultiNotificationMode(successFunc,errorFunc);

Comment: The link is now broken. Please edit your answer and include the actual code so it will help other people reading this answer.

Comment: Fixed the link!

Answer (score 2):

> You need to enable multi-notifications for Android.

```
PushManager.setMultiNotificationMode(context);
```